# How to highlight certain table rows in Plotly?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-python

In my table from a dataset I need to highlight rows in bold that contain "All" in columns `Building`, `Floor` or `Teams`:

[image]

My code :

```
headerColor = 'darkgrey'
rowEvenColor = 'lightgrey'
rowOddColor = 'white'

fig_occ_fl_team = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
  header=dict(
    values=list(final_table_occ_fl_team.columns),
    line_color='black',
    fill_color=headerColor,
    align=['left','left','left','left','left','left','left','left','left','left'],
    font=dict(color='black', size=9)
  ),
  cells=dict(
    values=[final_table_occ_fl_team['Building'], 
            final_table_occ_fl_team['Floor'], 
            final_table_occ_fl_team['Team'], 
            final_table_occ_fl_team['Number of Desks'], 
            final_table_occ_fl_team['Avg Occu (#)'], 
            final_table_occ_fl_team['Avg Occu (%)'], 
            final_table_occ_fl_team['Avg Occu 10-4 (#)'], 
            final_table_occ_fl_team['Avg Occu 10-4 (%)'], 
            final_table_occ_fl_team['Max Occu (#)'], 
            final_table_occ_fl_team['Max Occu (%)'], 
           ],
    line_color='black',
    # 2-D list of colors for alternating rows
    fill_color = [[rowOddColor,rowEvenColor]*56],
    align = ['left','left','left','left','left','left','left','left','left','left'],
    font = dict(color = 'black', size = 7)
    ))
])

fig_occ_fl_team.show()
```

Dataset head :

```
data = {'Building': {0: 'All',
  1: '1LWP',
  2: '1LWP',
  3: '1LWP',
  4: '1LWP',
  5: '1LWP',
  6: '1LWP',
  7: '1LWP',
  8: '1LWP',
  9: '1LWP'},
 'Floor': {0: 'All',
  1: 'All',
  2: '2nd',
  3: '2nd',
  4: '2nd',
  5: '2nd',
  6: '2nd',
  7: '2nd',
  8: '2nd',
  9: '2nd'},
 'Team': {0: 'All',
  1: 'All',
  2: 'All',
  3: 'Anderson/Money',
  4: 'Banking & Treasury',
  5: 'Charities',
  6: 'Client Management',
  7: 'Compliance, Legal & Risk',
  8: 'DFM',
  9: 'Emmerson'},
 'Number of Desks': {0: 2297,
  1: 2008,
  2: 381,
  3: 22,
  4: 8,
  5: 19,
  6: 9,
  7: 41,
  8: 20,
  9: 33},
 'Avg Occu (#)': {0: 1261,
  1: 1126,
  2: 195,
  3: 14,
  4: 4,
  5: 9,
  6: 5,
  7: 21,
  8: 13,
  9: 18},
 'Avg Occu (%)': {0: '55%',
  1: '56%',
  2: '51%',
  3: '64%',
  4: '50%',
  5: '48%',
  6: '56%',
  7: '52%',
  8: '65%',
  9: '55%'},
 'Avg Occu 10-4 (#)': {0: 851,
  1: 759,
  2: 132,
  3: 8,
  4: 3,
  5: 6,
  6: 3,
  7: 14,
  8: 9,
  9: 12},
 'Avg Occu 10-4 (%)': {0: '37%',
  1: '38%',
  2: '35%',
  3: '37%',
  4: '38%',
  5: '32%',
  6: '34%',
  7: '35%',
  8: '45%',
  9: '37%'},
 'Max Occu (#)': {0: 1901,
  1: 1680,
  2: 274,
  3: 22,
  4: 6,
  5: 13,
  6: 7,
  7: 27,
  8: 17,
  9: 25},
 'Max Occu (%)': {0: '83%',
  1: '84%',
  2: '72%',
  3: '100%',
  4: '75%',
  5: '69%',
  6: '78%',
  7: '66%',
  8: '85%',
  9: '76%'}}
```

Comment: If you start from index 0, you need to highlight odd-indexed rows, right?

Comment: I need to make rows bold whenever 'Floor', 'Building', or 'Team' column says ALL

Answer (score 0):

You can add the bold style to your dataframe prior to creating the table as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame().from_dict(data)

indices = df.index[(df[["Building","Floor","Team"]] == "All").all(1)]

for i in indices:
    for j in range(len(df.columns)):
        df.iloc[i,j] = "<b>{}</b>".format(df.iloc[i,j])
```

You can now create the table, I increase the size of font to 12:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

headerColor = 'darkgrey'
rowEvenColor = 'lightgrey'
rowOddColor = 'white'

fig_occ_fl_team = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
  header=dict(
    values=list(df.columns),
    line_color='black',
    fill_color=headerColor,
    align=['left','left','left','left','left','left','left','left','left','left'],
    font=dict(color='black', size=9)
  ),
  cells=dict(
    values=[df['Building'], 
            df['Floor'], 
            df['Team'], 
            df['Number of Desks'], 
            df['Avg Occu (#)'], 
            df['Avg Occu (%)'], 
            df['Avg Occu 10-4 (#)'], 
            df['Avg Occu 10-4 (%)'], 
            df['Max Occu (#)'], 
            df['Max Occu (%)'], 
           ],
    line_color='black',
    # 2-D list of colors for alternating rows
    fill_color = [[rowOddColor,rowEvenColor]*56],
    align = ['left','left','left','left','left','left','left','left','left','left'],
    font = dict(color = 'black', size = 12)
    ))
])

fig_occ_fl_team.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

You will notice that the first and forth columns are bold. If you want to keep the original dataframe unchanged, you can use such that `df2 = df1.copy()`.